# Increasing potential in a voltage doubler

Tags: potential, electronics

When I use a sinusoidal input AC-voltage from -1 Volt to +1 V , the potential between the diode and the capacitor is increasing. But why do I reach a value of 2 Volt over the diode? I deliberately don't post this in the electronics forum.

After some time the voltage on the right side of the capacitor is +1 Volt. When the input voltage goes from 0 V to +1 V the potential on the right side of the capacitor also increases, what I can't understand. If I want to increase the potential I need more charges and a current right?

[image: voltage doubler]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The voltage across a capacitor cannot change when there is no current, so if there is no current, as the input voltage rises, the output voltage also rises.

There is no current (or almost no current) when the voltage across that diode is positive.

According to [*Wikipedia*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_doubler) there are better ways to make voltage doublers.

Comment: But why does the output voltage rise? Do you have an other example?

Comment: @kame When the diode does not conduct the capacitor keeps on charging and acts as a voltage source in series with the external applied voltage hence you get the output +2V.  In practice the load resistance connected at output is very high and the time period of input AC source is very larger than $5RC$ ensuring that the capacitor will charge instantly.